# Will my salat be accepted if I don't understand the meaning of what I am reciting?

Tags: salat, arabic

My language is not Arabic. While reciting Sura in Salat I don't understand the meaning of these Sura. I have tried to remember the meanings during Salat and found that I can't pray properly. Since I was trying to translate Arabic to my language, I lost where I was reciting. So, my question is:

> Will my Salat be accepted even if I don't understand the meaning of
>   what I am reciting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaam . Bismillah.

Your salaat is between you and God. God is fully aware of your intentions and basically everything else. God is Al'hakim, the perfect in knowledge. Sounds like you're on the right track already, Al'hamdulilah.

With that technicality aside, ayat [4:43](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/4/43/default.htm) suggests that it's important to know what you're saying.

Now here's the thing. Your salaat practice as you continue to do it, now and in the future will continue to evolve and ideally get better. As I see it, there's absolutely no harm is worshiping God in the language you're comfortable with. It's not like God won't understand you.

In the future, as you continue to return to the practice of salaat, you'll likely improve your repertoire of what you're able to understand and recite of the Qur'an (which is the Arabic chapters and ayat).

Next, whatever you are able to recite, Al'hamdulilah, work with what you got. Ayat [73:20](https://www.free-minds.org/quran/PM/73/20) demonstrates beautifully that God is okay with whatever you're able to recite.

> Your Lord knows that you rise a little less than two thirds of the night, and half of it, and one third of it; and a group of those who are with you. And God measures the night and the day. He knows that you will not be able to keep up, so He pardons you. **So read what is made easy of the Qur'an.** He knows that there will be sick among you, and others that go forth in the land seeking from the bounty of God, and others who are fighting in the cause of God, so read what you can of it. And hold the contact prayer and contribute towards purification and lend God a loan of righteousness. And whatever you put forth yourselves, you will find it with God, for it is better and a greater reward. And seek the forgiveness of God, for God is Forgiving, Merciful.

Other translations of this ayat can be found [here](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/73/20/default.htm).

Al'hamdulilah, so exciting. I wish you much success.

Answer (score 1):

God willing, you will be accepted, but you can memorize Surat Al-Fatihah and translate it into English and understand its meaning and pray it so your prayers are correct. And with time you can memorize small Surats to pray with them.
I ask God to help you to make the prayer

Comment: More detailed and informative answer is needed.